# function that creates all the possibilities

Tags: javascript

```
var parameter1 = "String";

var parameter 2 = "-";

function test(parameter1, parameter2)
```

var parameter1 = "String";

var parameter 2 = "-";

function test(parameter1, parameter2)

result:

String

S-tring

S-t-ring

S-t-r-ing

S-t-r-i-ng

S-t-r-i-n-g

S-t-r-in-g

S-t-ri-ng

S-t-ri-n-g

S-t-rin-g

S-tr-ing

S-tr-i-ng

S-tr-i-n-g

S-tr-in-g

S-tri-ng

S-tri-n-g

S-trin-g

St-ring

St-r-ing

St-r-i-ng

St-r-i-n-g

St-r-in-g

St-ri-ng

St-ri-n-g

St-rin-g

Str-ing

Str-i-ng

Str-i-n-g

Str-in-g

Stri-ng

Stri-n-g

Strin-g

**So far tried to achieve this result but nothing is worked any help to get this result is appreciated. Thank you **
*i tried this way but i want to get exact output as above result*

```
     var array1=["S","T","R","I","N","G"];
      var array2=["-"];
     combos = [] //or combos = new Array(2);

     for(var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++)
    {
     for(var j = 0; j < array2.length; j++)
     {


        combos.push(array1[i] + array2[j])
     }
  console.log(combos);
}
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Please go read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: You haven't asked us a question, or told us about any kind of problem you're having. This isn't a free write-my-code service. We'll _help_ you, but we won't _do all your work for you_. Please show us what effort you've made so far to achieve your goal, and explain exactly what issue you're facing in achieving it. (hint: "I haven't started yet" or "I don't know what to do" isn't a problem, it simply indicates a lack of personal effort and/or research. You're asking volunteers for their free time, so in return we'd expect you to have spent some of your own time on the issue first). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a generator for getting parts of a string and iterate this values by checking if the right side has some character to split. If that is the case call the function again with that string and map new pairs for the result set.

```js
function* split(string) {
    var i = 0;
    while (++i < string.length) {
        yield [string.slice(0, i), string.slice(i)];
    }
}

function fn(string, delimiter) {
    const join = l => r => [l, r].join(delimiter);
    var result = [string],
        parts;
    for (var [left, right] of split(string)) {
        parts = join(left);
        if (right.length > 1) {
            result.push(...fn(right, delimiter).map(parts));
        } else {
            result.push(parts(right));
        }
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(fn('String', '-'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```